# Running a heavy cmd process from a servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a heavy CMD process (~5 min) that I need to run from a servlet on client demand.

I also want to be able to forward some of the process's output to the client. (percentage of the progress)

Tried a couple of approaches but could not make it work...

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP request will time out in five minutes.  Clients won't like waiting, either.

My recommendation would be to do this asynchronously using an Executor.

You can provide progress information by adding a second HTTP request to provide it and have the client make an AJAX call to that URL.